# ipad - mootool mouseout event?

Tags: javascript, ipad, mootools

I have a button.

When i mouseenter on this button. A content will display:block;

When mouseout , this content will display:none;

It run well on PC

Now with ipad.

If i want to show content , i have to touch on button. Ok

But when want to hidden content ? how to do ? (i don't want to use touchstart, touchend )

in this under link, 
http://www.steadfastcreative.com/

we can see the NAV controller when mouseover.
On ipad we can see the nav when touch.

And when we touch some where but image , then NAV will hidden

How to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no mouse move (without touch) paradigm with touch devices, therefore you have to use buttons or gestures.

Comment: there is no mouse move and mouse out for iPad . But the first tap if mousehover event is registered works as a mouse over . What about the mouse event is there any event in iPad which can be used as a mouse out event.